# Error in java program related to Map

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

I have developed a application in which user select the particular folder and it counts all the java files in that folder plus the line of code individually in those files and show at console but in a java project there are so many packages and right now I have to navigate until a particular package , I want to modify the application in such a way that when user select the particular project, he will then further navigate to only src folder and from src folder all the packages containing java files line of code will be counted.

```
public class abc {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws FileNotFoundException
     */
    private static int totalLineCount = 0;
    private static int totalFileScannedCount = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("C:" + File.separator));
        chooser.setDialogTitle("FILES ALONG WITH LINE NUMBERS");
        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
        if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            File directory = new File(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());

            List<File> files = getFileListing(directory);

            //print out all file names, in the the order of File.compareTo()
            for (File file : files) {
                System.out.println("Directory: "+file);
                result = getFileLineCount(file);
                totalFileScannedCount +=  result.size();
            }


            System.out.println("*****************************************");
            System.out.println("FILE NAME FOLLOWED BY LOC");
            System.out.println("*****************************************");

            for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : result.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " ==> " + entry.getValue());
            }
            System.out.println("*****************************************");
            System.out.println("SUM OF FILES SCANNED ==>" + "\t" + totalFileScannedCount);
            System.out.println("SUM OF ALL THE LINES ==>" + "\t" + totalLineCount);

        }

    }

    public static Map<String, Integer> getFileLineCount(File directory) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        File[] files = directory.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {

            @Override
            public boolean accept(File directory, String name) {
                if (name.endsWith(".java")) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
                int lineCount = 0;
                try {
                    for (lineCount = 0; scanner.nextLine() != null; lineCount++);
                } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                    result.put(file.getName(), lineCount);
                    totalLineCount += lineCount;
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Recursively walk a directory tree and return a List of all
     * Files found; the List is sorted using File.compareTo().
     *
     * @param aStartingDir is a valid directory, which can be read.
     */
    static public List<File> getFileListing(
            File aStartingDir) throws FileNotFoundException {
        validateDirectory(aStartingDir);
        List<File> result = getFileListingNoSort(aStartingDir);
        Collections.sort(result);
        return result;
    }

    // PRIVATE //
    static private List<File> getFileListingNoSort(
            File aStartingDir) throws FileNotFoundException {
        List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
        File[] filesAndDirs = aStartingDir.listFiles();
        List<File> filesDirs = Arrays.asList(filesAndDirs);
        for (File file : filesDirs) {
            if(file.isDirectory()) {
                result.add(file); 
            }
            if (!file.isFile()) {
                //must be a directory
                //recursive call!
                List<File> deeperList = getFileListingNoSort(file);
                result.addAll(deeperList);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Directory is valid if it exists, does not represent a file, and can be read.
     */
    static private void validateDirectory(
            File aDirectory) throws FileNotFoundException {
        if (aDirectory == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Directory should not be null.");
        }
        if (!aDirectory.exists()) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Directory does not exist: " + aDirectory);
        }
        if (!aDirectory.isDirectory()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Is not a directory: " + aDirectory);
        }
        if (!aDirectory.canRead()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Directory cannot be read: " + aDirectory);
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is the issue with this approach is that if in java project named TESTRESULT there are 3 packages and each package having 2 files each then in the result on console it shows file name followed by loc of only the latest package only lets say in a java projest 3 packages named abc, def and tyu

```
com.abc package having files --->abc.java
com.def package having files --->abc.java
com.tyu package having files --->FileBrowse.java , FileCountLine.java

the outcome shown in console is... 


    Directory: C:\Users\vaio\Desktop\Demo\TESTRESULT\.settings
    Directory: C:\Users\vaio\Desktop\Demo\TESTRESULT\bin
    Directory: C:\Users\vaio\Desktop\Demo\TESTRESULT\src
    Directory: C:\Users\vaio\Desktop\Demo\TESTRESULT\src\com
    Directory: C:\Users\vaio\Desktop\Demo\TESTRESULT\src\com\abc
    Directory: C:\Users\vaio\Desktop\Demo\TESTRESULT\src\com\def
    Directory: C:\Users\vaio\Desktop\Demo\TESTRESULT\src\tyu
    *****************************************
    FILE NAME FOLLOWED BY LOC
    *****************************************
    FileBrowse.java ==> 95
    FileCountLine.java ==> 53
    *****************************************
    SUM OF FILES SCANNED ==> 4
    SUM OF ALL THE LINES ==> 296
```

which is not perfect. please advise HOW IT WILL SHOW FILENAME FOLLOWED BY LOC for all the files

What I think is In the method that reads the files and the line count, you create a NEW Map for each directory and re-assign it to the same result. Since you do not display the data before you re-assign the Map, the previous Map is no longer accessible and by the time you get to the display you only have a Map for the last directory. Instead, you should maintain a single Map and insert new values from each directory into the same Map.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {  
            //...  
            for (File file : files) {  
                System.out.println("Directory: "+file);  
                result = getFileLineCount(file);
```

Right there you get a Map back from `getFileLineCount()`, and assign it to result. This discards the previously created result Map, and you lose everything that was already there. You have a few options:

1. Pass the result Map into the `getFileLineCount()` method so you can add results to the one Map, rather than creating a new Map for each folder inside the `getFileLineCount()` method
2. Take the results from `getLineCount()` and copy them into the result Map rather than replacing the result Map
3. Create another collection, like a Map like: `Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>` (which would map the results returned by the `getFileLineCount()` method to the name of the directory those results pertain to), or `List<Map<String, Integer>>` (which would be a simple list of the results returned by `getFileLineCount()` without any mapping to the parent directory).

Please advise how to refactor my code ,Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
result.put(file, lineCount);
```

instead of

```
result.put(file.getName(), lineCount);
```

And when you print the result you could print the pretty file name. Like this:

```
for (Map.Entry<File, Integer> entry : result.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey().getName() + " ==> " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Of course map should be then declared as: `Map.Entry<File, Integer>`

---

Of course this can be improved a lot but with minimal changes you could have this (that is actually doing what you expect, please just change to print the name if you don't want the entire path):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class abc {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws FileNotFoundException
     */
    private static int totalLineCount = 0;
    private static int totalFileScannedCount = 0;

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("C:" + File.separator));
        chooser.setDialogTitle("FILES ALONG WITH LINE NUMBERS");
        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
        if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            Map<File, Integer> result = new HashMap<File, Integer>();
            File directory = new File(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());

            List<File> files = getFileListing(directory);

            // print out all file names, in the the order of File.compareTo()
            for (File file : files) {
                System.out.println("Directory: " + file);
                getFileLineCount(result, file);
            }

            System.out.println("*****************************************");
            System.out.println("FILE NAME FOLLOWED BY LOC");
            System.out.println("*****************************************");

            for (Map.Entry<File, Integer> entry : result.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println(entry.getKey().getAbsolutePath() + " ==> " + entry.getValue());
            }
            System.out.println("*****************************************");
            System.out.println("SUM OF FILES SCANNED ==>" + "\t" + totalFileScannedCount);
            System.out.println("SUM OF ALL THE LINES ==>" + "\t" + totalLineCount);
        }

    }

    public static void getFileLineCount(final Map<File, Integer> result, final File directory)
            throws FileNotFoundException {
        File[] files = directory.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {

            public boolean accept(final File directory, final String name) {
                if (name.endsWith(".java")) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                totalFileScannedCount++;
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
                int lineCount = 0;
                try {
                    for (lineCount = 0; scanner.nextLine() != null; lineCount++) {
                        ;
                    }
                } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                    result.put(file, lineCount);
                    totalLineCount += lineCount;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Recursively walk a directory tree and return a List of all Files found;
     * the List is sorted using File.compareTo().
     * 
     * @param aStartingDir
     *            is a valid directory, which can be read.
     */
    static public List<File> getFileListing(final File aStartingDir) throws FileNotFoundException {
        validateDirectory(aStartingDir);
        List<File> result = getFileListingNoSort(aStartingDir);
        Collections.sort(result);
        return result;
    }

    // PRIVATE //
    static private List<File> getFileListingNoSort(final File aStartingDir) throws FileNotFoundException {
        List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
        File[] filesAndDirs = aStartingDir.listFiles();
        List<File> filesDirs = Arrays.asList(filesAndDirs);
        for (File file : filesDirs) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                result.add(file);
            }
            if (!file.isFile()) {
                // must be a directory
                // recursive call!
                List<File> deeperList = getFileListingNoSort(file);
                result.addAll(deeperList);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Directory is valid if it exists, does not represent a file, and can be
     * read.
     */
    static private void validateDirectory(final File aDirectory) throws FileNotFoundException {
        if (aDirectory == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Directory should not be null.");
        }
        if (!aDirectory.exists()) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Directory does not exist: " + aDirectory);
        }
        if (!aDirectory.isDirectory()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Is not a directory: " + aDirectory);
        }
        if (!aDirectory.canRead()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Directory cannot be read: " + aDirectory);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1+ for the answer, 10+ for reading through that entire question.

Comment: @Spaeth thanks a lot, could you please show in code terms as I have done at which placed changes need to be done that will be a great help

Comment: @Spaeth could you please make changes in my above code and then please write the complete code as I have done that will be a great help, as I still confused where changes need to be done please help

Comment: The code was changes as commented in the answer, minimal stuff were changed ;)

Comment: @Spaeth..thanks for the updated changes could you please modify as I have done with starting from J file chooser I want an jfile chooser dialog box to be get opened as I was doing , I don't want path to be hardcoded, thanks, I have tested it here it is running perfectly but please incorporate it with my Jfile chooser control, thanks a lot for helping, thanks

Comment: added it back as it was, my fault ;)

Comment: @Spaeth..YEAH IT WORKS cool Man , Thanks from bottom of my heart but the only issue is left that I have project name Reg which I have selected from jfile chooser by browsing to project name itself and selecting it Now the project name Reg has two packages and both the packages have single file each but while in results it is showing SUM OF FILES SCANNED ==>3 , instead it should be two ,PLEASE ADVISE FOR THIS ALSO, Thanks in advance once again

Comment: @Spaeth..YEAH IT WORKS cool Man , Thanks from bottom of my heart but the only issue is left that I have project name Reg which I have selected from jfile chooser by browsing to project name itself and selecting it Now the project name Reg has two packages and both the packages have single file each but while in results it is showing SUM OF FILES SCANNED ==>3 , instead it should be two ,PLEASE ADVISE FOR THIS ALSO, Thanks in advance once again

Comment: @Naresh: you'll want to up-vote Spaeth's answer (click on the up arrow to the left of the answer) and accept it (click on the check mark to the left of it).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels it is showing me that it requires 15 reputation at least but Spaeth is amazing talent, He has made my day thanks to him

Comment: Nice answer.  Wanted to add that, in general, I prefer to use the File object (if there is one) instead of the String name of the file.

Comment: @Spaeth could you also please advise for why SUM OF FILES SCANNED IS SHOWING MORE

Comment: Yes, the problem is you should increment it just when the file is scanned. the like you perform: `totalFileScannedCount += result.size();` should be move to here: `if (file.isFile()) {`
`Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));`
So, the increment will happen just in case that the file should be considered.

Comment: @Spaeth could you once again please update the code with this following change that will be a great help

Comment: @Spaeth done man it's working once again thanks from bottom of my heart for this valuable suggestion it is showing now exactly the files scanned

Comment: Please use the last version with the `totalFileScannedCount++`. You are welcome.

Comment: @Spaeth could you please update the code once again so that I can once again validate that will be a great help

Comment: @Spaeth one thing  more that I was thinking that rite now it is also counting white space in files as line number that is counting it in line of code I want to exclude this that is no white space line is to be considered and also the commented line should also be ignored please advise what changes need to be done for that,

Comment: @Spaeth regarding e last version with the totalFileScannedCount++, could you please update the code so that will be a great help

Comment: @Spaeth ok validated for totalFileScannedCount++ working perfectly thanks a lot , Amazing help provided by you thanks a lot

Comment: @Spaeth rite now as I was observing that also counting white space in files as line number that is counting it in line of code I want to exclude this that is no white space line is to be considered and also the commented line should also be ignored please advise what changes need to be done for that, it will be a great help if could you in the updated piece of code what updations were being done , thanks in advance

Comment: just compares the read string with "", and count if not equals to "" (empty) like `if(!readString.trim().equals("")) lineCount++`, please open a new question commenting exactly your question... these comments are too long to be handled just in one question.

Comment: @Spaeth a new question has been opened at the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279469/want-to-remove-the-remove-the-whitespcaes-with-java-built-in-methods#comment14834481_11279469