# Want to remove the whitespaces, with java built in methods

Tags: java, string, io

I have developed an application that read how many files are there in a java package inside the java project and count the line of code in those individual files to for example in a java project if there are 2 packages having 4 individual files then total files read will be 4 and if those 4 files having 10 piece of lines of code in each file then 4*10 is total 40 lines of code in overall project ...below is my piece of code

```
     private static int totalLineCount = 0;
        private static int totalFileScannedCount = 0;

        public static void main(final String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("C:" + File.separator));
            chooser.setDialogTitle("FILES ALONG WITH LINE NUMBERS");
            chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
            chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
            if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                Map<File, Integer> result = new HashMap<File, Integer>();
                File directory = new File(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());

                List<File> files = getFileListing(directory);

                // print out all file names, in the the order of File.compareTo()
                for (File file : files) {
                   // System.out.println("Directory: " + file);
                    getFileLineCount(result, file);
                    //totalFileScannedCount += result.size(); //saral
                }

                System.out.println("*****************************************");
                System.out.println("FILE NAME FOLLOWED BY LOC");
                System.out.println("*****************************************");

                for (Map.Entry<File, Integer> entry : result.entrySet()) {
                    System.out.println(entry.getKey().getAbsolutePath() + " ==> " + entry.getValue());
                }
                System.out.println("*****************************************");
                System.out.println("SUM OF FILES SCANNED ==>" + "\t" + totalFileScannedCount);
                System.out.println("SUM OF ALL THE LINES ==>" + "\t" + totalLineCount);
            }

        }

        public static void getFileLineCount(final Map<File, Integer> result, final File directory)
                throws FileNotFoundException {
            File[] files = directory.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {

                public boolean accept(final File directory, final String name) {
                    if (name.endsWith(".java")) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
            for (File file : files) {
                if (file.isFile()) {
                    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
                    int lineCount = 0;
                    totalFileScannedCount ++; //saral
                    try {
                        for (lineCount = 0; scanner.nextLine() != null; ) {
                            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
   String line = scanner.nextLine().trim();
   if (!line.isEmpty()) {
     lineCount++;
   }
                        }
                    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                        result.put(file, lineCount);
                        totalLineCount += lineCount;
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        /**
         * Recursively walk a directory tree and return a List of all Files found;
         * the List is sorted using File.compareTo().
         * 
         * @param aStartingDir
         *            is a valid directory, which can be read.
         */
        static public List<File> getFileListing(final File aStartingDir) throws FileNotFoundException {
            validateDirectory(aStartingDir);
            List<File> result = getFileListingNoSort(aStartingDir);
            Collections.sort(result);
            return result;
        }

        // PRIVATE //
        static private List<File> getFileListingNoSort(final File aStartingDir) throws FileNotFoundException {
            List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
            File[] filesAndDirs = aStartingDir.listFiles();
            List<File> filesDirs = Arrays.asList(filesAndDirs);
            for (File file : filesDirs) {
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    result.add(file);
                }
                if (!file.isFile()) {
                    // must be a directory
                    // recursive call!
                    List<File> deeperList = getFileListingNoSort(file);
                    result.addAll(deeperList);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        /**
         * Directory is valid if it exists, does not represent a file, and can be
         * read.
         */
        static private void validateDirectory(final File aDirectory) throws FileNotFoundException {
            if (aDirectory == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Directory should not be null.");
            }
            if (!aDirectory.exists()) {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("Directory does not exist: " + aDirectory);
            }
            if (!aDirectory.isDirectory()) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Is not a directory: " + aDirectory);
            }
            if (!aDirectory.canRead()) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Directory cannot be read: " + aDirectory);
            }
        }
```

but the issue is that it also count the white space lines while calculating the line of code for the individual files , which it should not , please advise what modifications I need to do in my program so that it should not count the white spaces while calculating the line of code for the individual files .

The idea that was coming to my mind was just compares the read string with "", and count if not equals to "" (empty) like if(!readString.trim().equals("")) lineCount++ 
Please advise for this

Comment: You should probably trim lines before comparing them. Otherwise, lines that contain only spaces will still pass.

Comment: @Antimony could you please update my code with the logic that you have told , that will really help me to understand thanks a lot

Comment: @Naresh: All he's telling you to do is call `trim()` on a String, getting the trimmed String that is returned, and using this in  your comparisons. Surely you can try to do this on your own first, no?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thanks a lot for supporting I have tried here but it does not work

Comment: @Naresh: then show us your attempt as an edit above, show us your errors, and ask your questions. Please don't ask us to write code for you or to "update" your code though. That's not how StackOverflow works.

Comment: Please advise How to achieve that I am updating my tried piece of code within seconds

Comment: Are you having trouble with lines of code with whitespaces in them, or completely blank lines getting counted as lines of code?

Comment: @Thomas yeah completely blank lines getting counted as lines of code for example in a java files if there are 8 actual code lines and 8  completely blank lines ,then total line of code is coming as 16 which should not it should be 8 that is the 8 actual line of code and rest 8 whitespace line should be ignored , Please advise

Comment: You're not showing us your `trim()` attempt. You said that you've tried it and will show it to us, but it's nowhere in your most recent post. What gives?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I have done that but it is not working  and sorry for delay

Comment: @Thomas please advise any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestions:

- Scanner has a `hasNextLine()` method which you should use. I would use it as the condition of a while loop.
- Then get the line inside the while loop by calling `nextLine()` just once inside of the loop.
- Again call `trim()` on your Strings that are read in. I still don't see your attempt at this in the latest code update!
- A key concept when calling methods on Strings is that they are immutable, and the methods called on them do not change the underlying String, and `trim()` is no different: The String that it is called on is unchanged, but the String *returned* by the method ***is*** changed, and in fact is trimmed.
- String has an `isEmpty()` method that  you should call after trimming the String.

So don't do:

```
try {
    for (lineCount = 0; scanner.nextLine() != null; ) {
        if(!readString.trim().equals("")) lineCount++; // updated one
    }
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    result.put(file, lineCount);
    totalLineCount += lineCount;
}
```

Instead do:

```
int lineCount = 0;
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
   String line = scanner.nextLine().trim();
   if (!line.isEmpty()) {
     lineCount++;
   }
}
```

Comment: Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
                int lineCount = 0;
                totalFileScannedCount ++; //saral
                try {
                 /*for (lineCount = 0; scanner.nextLine() != null; lineCount++) { //saral
                        ;
                        }*/
                 for (lineCount = 0; scanner.nextLine() != null;) { //saral
                        while (scanner.nextLine() != null)
                        {
                         
                         
                        }
                        }

Comment: @NareshSaxena: comments cannot hold code. Please see edit to my answer.

Comment: ..no that also don't work I have tried your editied code also but upon executing, some of all the lines is coming as o ..!!

Comment: please advise as I am stuck up with this problem

Comment: @NareshSaxena: You should use System.out.println(...) calls to check the Strings that are being read in, check whether they contribute to the count. In other words -- debug your code.

Comment: @HHovercraft Full Of Eels 7 done that but still does not getting success

Comment: @HHovercraft Full Of Eels 7 now debug it is taking now all the lines and not taking whtespaces but still the overall sum of all the lines is 0 thats the point of worry man..!1